# Will repeatedly searching and clicking increase search engine rankings?

Tags: seo, ranking, google-ranking

My website is showing in Google search for a particular keyword. I am now searching for my website many times with this keyword. Is doing so going to effect the position of the website within the search results?

Will it also effect rankings for other pages on the site?

Answer (score 3):

**Not at all fortunately!** Imagine that it will be so easy to pay a thousands of people to click on a site to optimise its positions.

[Here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google) are some tips to increase a site's position on Google.

However, you need to know that clicking on a site on Google increases its position for you if you're logged in to your Google account because Google wants to keep the history of your actions.

Comment: Google uses the query log and other metrics to know what people are searching for, the SERPs, and user activities to build better results. However, G can also look for abuses such as repeated queries and attempts to manipulate results. Basically, genuine trends will effect the SERPs temporarily, and manipulation will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Only what crawlers can see is getting used for pagerank. In other word it does not matter what you find on other pages as long as these pages are not linking to you with these specific keywords. So in other words, search for as many keywords for your site as you like, as long as you dont put them on your page or in your backing links, there will be no affect

Comment: Google uses signals other than from its crawler.   Google pays attention to usability signals such as click through rate, and site retention rate.     Repeatedly clicking on your own site might increase the CTR favorably, but I'd imagine that Google has systems to detect self clicks.

Comment: I would argue that this is hear say. And even if,...you would never be able to make so many clicks without the propper bot knowlage so that it has effect. Because you would have to disconnect yourself from all cokies and change IP´s for each action because otherwise you would count as one unique visit, no matter how often you are doing it.

Comment: Stephen is exactly right. It is not hear say. Much of this can be evidenced in trending. There was an interesting experiment on this a while ago where the results did temporarily change the SERPs, however, if you try to manipulate the SERPs this way yourself, you will find that Google will black-list you very quickly.